# ARkit function setWorldOrigin problem of rotation and drift away

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

current flow

detect imageAnchor -> setWorldOrigin to that anchor

however, the origin move away and rotate sometime.....

I cannot use it to be the reference point of my ARworld

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Image tracking can be a bit unstable, instead of assigning the transform position to the world origin on detection can you instead just attach your entities as a child of the image anchor, that was as the anchor moves so will all the content automatically.

Comment: so, [rootNode - >imageNode ->all myNode] instead of [rootNode(imageNode)->all my Node]?